# Error in wordpress export

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, export

I am using WordPress 3.5.2 version. When i try to export xml file it show me this type error.
What i have to do.

File not found

Firefox can't find the file at http://example.com/wp-admin/export.php?download=true&content=posts&cat=0&post_author=0&post_start_date=0&post_end_date=0&post_status=0&page_author=0&page_start_date=0&page_end_date=0&page_status=0&submit=Download+Export+File.

```
Check the file name for capitalization or other typing errors.
Check to see if the file was moved, renamed or deleted.
```

Comment: I have a similar problem on my own site.I think that it originated from Woocommerce variations. Because export pages, posts, products etc. only dostn export woocommerce variations.

Answer (score 1):

Here 's an update. Ran into the same exact problem, and..

It 's positive, it 's a memory issue. Just like what jjava00 said above, increase the memory_limit.

- File to edit : php.ini
- Line to edit : 232
- string : memory_limit = 32MB.
- If you can't find it on line 232, search for this string memory_limit, you 'll get there for sure.

Not sure if each hosting has the same default setup, but my default is 32MB. I increased it to 64MB.

Not all of us have this privilege to edit this php.ini file. Including me. I 'm on a shared hosting. So here 're what I did:

1. I edit the php.ini of my local apache - set the memory_limit to 64MB. (I use appserv)
2. Upload it to the root of my web dir (www or public_html or htdocs or whatever).
   .. and That 's it.

The export.php script can then create the xml file we need to download - as now there 're enough memory resources to do so, and it can be downloaded. Problem solved.

Source: [WordPress Forum](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/error-export-file?replies=6#post-1106903)

Let me know if there have also problem.